# Concat in query or loop through results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What would be better? (consider performance, maintainability, readability)

Pseudocode:

```
SELECT CONCAT('<td>', user_firstname, '</td>') FROM TableA;
```

OR

```
$results = SELECT user_firstname FROM TableA
foreach($result as $fname) {
    $row .= '<td>'.$fname.'</td>';
}
```

I feel like doing it in query would be better because PHP wouldn't have to loop through it (assume ~20,000 rows in TableA). But I also think whoever sees this code in the future would wonder why you would do that in a query.

EDIT: The main reason I ask is our php looping in other places for this dataset is very memory costly.

Comment: do you have an app you're thinking about specifically?  if so, why not try both ways and run benchmarks?

Comment: Imagine if you suddenly had to do it in a `<div></div>` element.

Comment: @dax It's a good way for checking but not optimal because maybe things will change on large queries etc.

Comment: Normally I would not expect to get data from a db that was already formatted for display. I would just add the markup when echo'ing it

Comment: Don't put un-necessary work on the database side. Adding an extra web server is trivial, adding another database server is definitely not.

Comment: Why are you writing display oriented code in SQL?  What about SOC?

Comment: It's always a bad idea to mix presentation and data retrieval logic. I wouldn't recommend first approach.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Sadly, our setup is the opposite, easy to add a DB server, not a web server, we have 1 dedicated web server, and won't be getting more soon because of cost (have to have dedicated- HIPPA)

Comment: @Raymond If you're experiencing performance issues have you looked into the appropriate caching options for your setup?

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely opt for returning plain data and manipulating it with PHP. You are no doubt going to be looping through the results anyway, so why not just echo the tags either side at the sime time?

That, however, isn't my main reasoning - if you end up using the same data for multiple instances you can cache and re-use the results, implementing the returned data into different templates as per usage requirements (not possible if the returned data set has view-specific code on every row).

Also, the query should be separate from the code that creates the view anyway, so when updating the final markup, it will be easier to modify the PHP that's creating the markup (in the same file as the other markup), than finding the query to make the markup changes. `echo '<th>'.$field.'</th>';` is also much clearer as to it's intentions than just `echo $field;`.

At the end of the day it's down to personal preference, but as getting into good practice for MVC structures and generally clean and maintainable code, I would definitely vote for the markup to be done in PHP

**TL;DR**

- Use PHP - you'll probably be looping with it anyway
- `echo '<th>'.$field.'</th>';` has clearer intentions (more readable) than `echo $field;`
- If the data is to be used elsewhere you can cache the single query for re-use with a different markup template, rather than making multiple queries adding different wrapped tags each time
- Databases are best left to data retrieval for legibility (hence the MVC movement), this data can then be manipulated by a language more suited to the job such as PHP

Answer (score 2):

If you are returning 20,000 rows, presumably you have to loop through them anyway.  If so, there is minimal performance difference between doing the work in php or in MySQL.

In favor of doing it in MySQL is that the database can trivially do this type of work, and many databases can take advantage of multiple processors to make it run faster.  I prefer returning the results in the way they are needed, when that is easy.

In favor of doing it in php is that you are returning fewer characters from the database, so there might actually be a small gain in performance over the network.  This would be offset by the work on the application side.

I would side with doing it in the database for maintenance and readability reasons.  The logic for extracting the data is in one place rather than two, and expressed in one language rather than two.

Comment: I would say the opposite. The webserver is where markup should be applied not the database. Doing it on the database server is likely to have a higher cost than doing it at the point of display, in terms of memory usage and db server load.

Comment: @Anigel . . . If you would say the opposite, then you should do so in an answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff there is already an answer saying the opposite. Which I have +1'd which is how I believe SO is supposed to work. Just making a simple comment why I don't think this particular answer is the best

Comment: I agree with @Anigel. Formatting for presentation needs to be done at the application layer, not the database.

Answer (score 1):

do it on the PHP end - why? to keep your data layer separate from your presentation layer.  SQL should have one job, and only one job.  That is to query and retrieve raw data.  The second you start having SQL do stuff it's not designed to is the second your application starts going downhill and starts becoming a pain to maintain.  Use the servers as intended, and retrieve your data from SQL, pretty it up on the web server end (drop it into tables, etc)